# JTable to Windows clipboard

Tags: java, windows, clipboard

I'm trying to get the contents of a `JTable` onto the Windows system clipboard. My basic approach is outlined below.

```
            StringBuilder sbf = new StringBuilder();
            for (i=0; i<numrows; i++) {
                for (j=0; j<numcols; j++) {
                    sbf.append(jTable1.getValueAt(i, j) );
                    if (j<numcols-1) sbf.append("\t");
                }
                sbf.append("\n");
            }
            StringSelection stsel = new StringSelection(sbf.toString());
            system = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            system.setContents(stsel,stsel);
```

The above works great for modest data sets.  For slightly larger data sets I'm able to avoid an `OutOfMemoryError` by using the constructor `StringBuilder(int capacity)` because I have an estimate of the character count.  Unfortunately this also generates `OutOfMemoryError` for still larger data sets.

My question is 'how can I get the contents of a "large-ish" `JTable` onto the clipboard?'  I don't want to use -Xms for the JVM and I don't need the `StringBuilder` object except as shown above. If it can be done without the intermediate `StringBuilder`, I'm expecting that there should be only a small amount of additional memory required for the JVM to execute this because I already have the data in the `JTable` and the new allocation is for the OS, not the JVM. Although not desirable, I'm open to using a temporary file but once the file is written I don't know how to open a stream for this file to the clipboard.  Is it possible to use some form of `PipedOutputStream` or ..., ideally without a temporary file?

Update July 2022: I've found that the default JRE on most Win10 machines in our office is typically 1.8.0_212. For the amount of data in this example the problem does not occur with 1.8.0_291. Yes I know they're both pretty old by now but I'm currently not forcing folks to upgrade their default installation. As you might expect, the problem also does not occur with the much more current version bundled with the JDK 17.0.3.1. Currently not sure what might happen with still larger data sets. So then, it seems this problem might be a non-issue depending on the user's JRE and if you're willing to force them to upgrade. Hope someone finds this useful. Thanks again to all for your help and input!

Comment: Well you do know Java is not renowned for its memory economy don't you? ;) Your idea of a temp file could be good but actually why do you need all this on the clipboard in the first place?

Comment: I'm thinking that it's the most convenient way to get it into Excel. Is there something better than copy/paste?  This amount of data is handled "seamlessly" by Office tools (Word, Excel, ...) and although I don't know the underlying mechanics they use, I'd like the same functionality and (similar) performance

Comment: Well of course if you streamed it to file as x.csv, Excel would open it by default on a Windows system. In your gui you could have a `java.awt.Desktop.open` button/link to do that

Comment: That's a bit better that my current workaround, which is writing a txt and asking the user to open it, select all, copy, and then paste to Excel.  But not by too much because the user still has the copy/paste operation because the new csv/Excel file needs to be merged with whatever else they're already working on in Excel.  Still, many thanks for your excellent input!!  I will probably implement if I can't find a more direct solution.

Comment: Well if you get them to keep it as a csv file you can merge as you see fit without 3rd party libraries such as Apache POI. Obviously it would be trivial to *append* the table to an existing csv file if the columns match by simply opening the target in append mode

Comment: Again excellent suggestions and I apologize that I haven't provided a more full context. The Excel file will likely have other non-csv stuff (pivot tables, formatting, ...) and keeping it as csv is not the right solution for this.  Likewise other tools that write directly to Excel are not appealing because those would require constraints on the destination (sheet name, starting cell, ...) The clipboard-based solution is strongly preferred here.  It's most convenient (to my knowledge) and what a user has come to expect these days.

Comment: At which point do you get the `OutOfMemoryError`? While filling your `StringBuilder`, when calling `toString()` or during `system.setContents(…)`?

Comment: It occurs while filling the 'StringBuilder' (i.e., w/in the loop). Apologies for the delayed response - I intended to revisit the problem and put the loop in a try/catch as I did previously just to get the row and column number but haven't had time so I'm speaking from memory now.  Hopefully this is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Swing already can do this:

```
jTable1.selectAll();
jTable1.getTransferHandler().exportToClipboard(jTable1,
    jTable1.getToolkit().getSystemClipboard(),
    TransferHandler.COPY);
```

Comment: Very cool but unfortunately this also throws OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but an offending example `JTable` has 713,681 rows.  There are nine columns: 1 `String` (<10 characters), 2 `Integer`s (range 0 < i < 99,999), and six `Double`s (range -1E6 < x < 1E6).  The `Double`s have only four decimals when they populate the `JTable` and so far as I've seen, the default `String` conversion returns the same.  This was my basis for using `StringBuilder(int capacity)`.